# How to create function that return promise from callback function

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, promise

I use javascript library that has api.

```
libapi.callnetwork(arg1,callback(data){
//handle data
}
```

then i create service function to call api like this

```
myFunction():Promise<any>{
  libapi.callnetwork(arg1,callback(data){
    return new Promise(resolve=>resolve(data));
  })
}
```

myFunction will get error because it must return promise or declare as void. How can i create function that return promise from this api?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The idea is not to create and return the promise from inside the callback, but to create it in the outside function (where you can `return` it) and only *resolve* the promise from the callback:

```
myFunction():Promise<any>{
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    libapi.callnetwork(arg1, callback(data){
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

or simply

```
myFunction():Promise<any>{
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    libapi.callnetwork(arg1, resolve);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla, grab the resolve function

```
let myFunction = () => {
    let resolve;
    let promise = new Promise(r => resolve = r);
    libapi.callnetwork(arg1, resolve);
    return promise;
};
```

Comment: No. Don't  do that. This is why deferreds were deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

```
myFunction():Promise<any>{
  let resolveFn = (data) => data;
  libapi.callnetwork(arg1, resolveFn);
  return new Promise(resolveFn);
}
```